# Add category thumbnail to default category list widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, categories, wp-list-categories

I created thumbnails for my post categories ( using an image ACF custom field called cat_thumbnail )
How can I add them to the default category sidebar widget, to display the thumb next to each category?
Ideally with a filter as I would prefer to not use a plugin for this.
I looked at the wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php file and this is how far I got:

```
if( !is_admin() ){
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'filter_function_name_8004', 10, 2 );
}
function filter_function_name_8004( $cat_args, $instance ){
echo 'ennou';
return $cat_args;
}
```

Thank you